# How to get the best saving SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have the following table:

```
ID  Name   Price  RRP
1   Shirt  10.00  20.00
2   Jeans  15.00  30.00
```

How would I retrieve the row with the biggest saving (ID 2)?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Id,Name,Price,RRP FROM TableName Order By (RRP-Price) Desc Limit 1
```

Comment: +1 for selecting the row as asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Price, RRP, RRP-Price AS saving 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY saving DESC
```